# Rest client in Xamarin Forms unable to connect to localhost

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin

I have a web api project that I am hosting in IISExpress from within Visual Studio and it is running ok on

```
http://localhost:9998/swagger/index.html
```

then I have another Visual Studio solution for my mobile development and I have code as follows:

```
public static string BaseAddress { get; set; }
BaseAddress = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? "https://10.0.2.2:5001" : "https://localhost:5001";
```

What I need is that HTTP Rest Client from my mobile code should call a method in the WebAPI project. So there I have some code as follows:

```
private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text)) {
            AppUser user = new AppUser() { 
                UserName = txtLogin.Text.Trim(), 
                Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim()
            };

            var restClient = new RestClient(App.BaseAddress);

            var restRequest = new RestRequest();
            restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
            restRequest.Resource = "api/ApplicationUser/Login";
            restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", (user), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

            var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

            if (response != null) {
                var x = response.Content;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Show validation message here.
        }
    }
```

However, the issue is that the request never reaches the WebAPI. I am running the web service in http not https yet it is not able to connect.

Any ideas what can be done to fix this so that I also review my web api source code too.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't connect to localhost on the mobile as it's not running on your device but on your pc. Use the ip address of your machine. Remeber the firewall settings

Comment: I am running IISExpress from Visual Studio and if I ping localhost I dont see any IP address. Does IISExpress from Visual Studio not have an IP Address?

Comment: IISExpress will bind to an address and port, use ipconfig to find your local ip address